# Conversion from Wei to Ether gives different results

Tags: transactions, ether, web3.py, polygon, sidechain

I'm trying to analyze the transaction of [this contract](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x95f57249e6dd394318025068a8bfc841ac6ec0dd), but sometimes when I try to convert from wei to ether value of tokens I got comma in different position than expected. This is how I proceed:

1)Fetch all transactions from Moralis API. 
2)Take the ABI of the contract, and from the tx_input I decode the transaction in this way:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(tx["to_address"]), abi=abi['result'])
func_obj, func_params = contract.decode_function_input(tx["input"])
```

3. I get the wei value of token sent to the contract selecting the `func_params` with the following path `func_params['amountsInOutMarketMaxFee'][0]` in the case of `Swap Function` invoked.

Everything is fine unless in some case when I try to convert some numbers from wei to ether value I got different numbers than seen in explorers. For example when I fetch the following transaction from the contract above:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xa2d59655b42f947dc619f456553476f7b5929ef1ec6da229409dde9d6fb9629d
I got the following value:

```
13045952229932174800
```

That's the same amount you get from the decoded input in the blockchain explorer page.
But if I try to convert the amount with the following function:

```
 Web3.fromWei(tx_data['amountsInOutMaxFee'][0], 'ether')
```

I got 13.04 while on the blockchain explorer the amount is 1.304
Why is there this lack? Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a calculation error. The number that appears in the event logs is `121ada717a2ea7cd` that correspond to `1304595222993217480`.

And the value in the question is `13045952229932174800`. It has an additional zero at the end. That number correspond to `b50c886ec5d28dd0` in hexadecimal, but there's nothing like it in the transaction logs.

Comment: you're right. What could I change of my procedure in order to get the right numbers?

Comment: @giacomomaraglino How did you get the number `13045952229932174800`? It is no clear from the question. If you used a script, you could share to see if it has a bug.

Comment: Sorry. I get from Moralis APIs a JSON like this for each transaction: https://pastebin.com/0m8fvQW4. Then I take the "input" field and I decode the transaction input as described in the original post. From the func_obj dictonary I take the value of 'amountsInOutMaxFee'

Comment: @giacomomaraglino Either Moralis is providing erroneous data, or there's a bug in the decoding. You haven't provided a runnable script so we can't test where is the error.

Comment: Here you can find a runnable code: https://pastebin.com/agaB5hR2 . I don't think it's a Moralis Bug because if you see from the explorer the decoded data you will get the same amount. Hope you can help me finding a solution. thanks.